# JS (Coffee-Script) is not working in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am writing a simple code like:

```
ready = ->
  $('div').click ->
  $(this).append "<span style='color:#f00;'>olol</span>"
$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

However nothing happens, when I click on div elements on my web-page. When I put it into the HTML file between  tags everything works!!! Please, help, it seems, that I've tried everything!

Answer (score 2):

You're not properly indenting the body of the click handler. This part:

```
$('div').click ->
$(this).append "<span style='color:#f00;'>olol</span>"
```

Will compile to:

```
$('div').click(function() {});

$(this).append("<span style='color:#f00;'>olol</span>");
```

As you can see the function in your click handler is empty. Fix it by indenting that second line:

```
$('div').click ->
  $(this).append "<span style='color:#f00;'>olol</span>"
```

Now that compiles as expected:

```
$('div').click(function() {
  return $(this).append("<span style='color:#f00;'>olol</span>");
});
```

Be mindful of whitespace when writing Coffeescript.